# Word count statistics like in MS Word on Delphi

Tags: delphi, count, ms-word, statistics, word-count

Could you explain how to count words in TMemo and show the results in TLabet or TEdit?
Is it possible? Also I would like to know how count similar words (duplicate words) quantity. Thank you.
PS: how can i found words density in the text? For example: word "dog" appears three times in the text. Word number of the text is 100. Therefore density of the word "dog" is 3%. (3/100 * 100%).

Comment: The simple answer is: 'You write an algorithm for it.'. Do you want us to do it for you?

Comment: 1. Extract the contents into a string. 2. Split that string on white space to get a list of words. 3. Lower case the list of words. 4. Iterate across the list of words adding to a dictionary used to count occurrences. That's it. Hope you are on modern delphi with the generic dictionary class.

Comment: @David: That will only almost work, since a general text might include punctuation. You don't want 'This is a text!' to be split into ('This', 'is', 'a', 'text!').

Comment: @andreas indeed so. Easy enough to handle.

Comment: @David: Actually, not. I have been working for more than 12 hours in a row now, and so I am a bit tired. Feel free to implement it in an answer of your own!

Comment: Yurios; I downvoted this question to say "I wish you had tried something and posted what you tried".    Your question evidences zero effort on your part. -1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the first part (`uses Character`),

```
function CountWordsInMemo(AMemo: TMemo): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
  IsWhite, IsWhiteOld: boolean;
  txt: string;
begin
  txt := AMemo.Text;
  IsWhiteOld := true;
  result := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(txt) do
  begin
    IsWhite := IsWhiteSpace(txt[i]);
    if IsWhiteOld and not IsWhite then
      inc(result);
    IsWhiteOld := IsWhite;
  end;
end;
```

For the second part,

```
function OccurrencesOfWordInMemo(AMemo: TMemo; const AWord: string): integer;
var
  LastPos: integer;
  len: integer;
  txt: string;
begin
  txt := AMemo.Text;
  result := 0;
  LastPos := 0;
  len := Length(AWord);
  repeat
    LastPos := PosEx(AWord, txt, LastPos + 1);
    if (LastPos > 0) and
      ((LastPos = 1) or not IsLetter(txt[LastPos-1])) and
      ((LastPos + len - 1 = length(txt)) or not IsLetter(txt[LastPos+len])) then
      inc(result);
  until LastPos = 0;
end;

function DensityOfWordInMemo(AMemo: TMemo; const AWord: string): real;
begin
  result := OccurrencesOfWordInMemo(AMemo, AWord) / CountWordsInMemo(AMemo);
end;
```

Comment: Please don't send WM_GETTEXT every single iteration of the loop. We're also going to need a dictionary of words to do the counting.

Comment: @David: I optimized the message. As for the second part, that depends on if the OP needs to find the occurrence of *every* word in the text, or only some *particular* word.

Comment: Thanks everyone for any help. But i can't deal with the code above. How can it show the results (statistics) it Tlabel or in TEdit? And how can i fond number of similar keywords in the text (i must wrote it in TEdit and get the results in TLabel) and count its density? would you help me with code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yurios: If you don't know how to show the result of a function in a TLabel or TEdit, then perhaps you need to read some basic Delphi tutorials first? http://delphi.about.com is a good place to start (Though right this minute the site seems to be suffering from having to wait on something at tqn.com, it normally is pretty responsive.)

Comment: @Yurios Assign to the `Caption` property of a `TLabel`. For an edit control, use the `Text` property. For a `TMemo` use the `Lines` property. If you don't know how to do that, you need to learn that before you even contemplate counting occurrences. Walk before you can run.

Comment: @menjaraz: No, it is perfectly sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a simpler, faster and better one from maXbox4:

```
{ Returns a count of the number of occurences of SubText in Text }
function CountOccurences( const SubText: string;
                             const Text: string): Integer;
begin
  Result:= Pos(SubText, Text); 
  if Result > 0 then
    Result:= (Length(Text)-Length(StringReplace(Text,SubText,'',
                                     [rfReplaceAll]))) div  Length(subtext);
end;  { CountOccurences }

println('keyword freq. '+itoa(CountOccurences('exit',memo1.text)));
```